# What are Mouse Acceleration profiles in the gnome-tweak-tool?

Tags: gnome, mouse, touchpad, configuration, gnome-tweak-tool

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and I could have sworn that in previous GNOME versions that the Mouse Acceleration profiles option wasn't there. So I am now rather intrigued into what they are and if they are only for the mouse or if they are also for the touchpad. It is currently set to `Default`, however there are three options:

- `Adaptive`
- `Default`
- `Flat`

[image: gnome-tweak-tool Mouse Acceleration Profiles]

I have tried them all but there doesn't seem to really be any difference. But perhaps that it because they only apply to the mouse (which I lack) and not the touchpad? Anyhow, what exactly are they? And what do the different ones do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Some digging unearthed information that is "[for developers and is not necessarily useful for users](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/pointer-acceleration.html)".

After trying the different settings, I experienced:

1. adaptive - Less precise than other modes while moving the mouse slowly or quickly. It's quite jittery.
2. default: Very smooth and accurate when moving short distances. If I move the pointer across the screen I'll occasionally overreach the target. This mode basically seems to begin with a slow acceleration and increase as the mouses speed increases.
3. flat: There is no acceleration. Moving short distances results in less precision than the default profile, but I can anticipate where the pointer will be a bit better when moving over large distances, which helps avoid the overreach. I read [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-completely-disable-mouse.html) that when playing FPS games you want this profile.

Comment: The link you provide says "libinput currently supports two profiles: 'adaptive' and 'flat'. The adaptive profile is the default profile for all devices and takes the current speed of the device into account when deciding on acceleration." So I don't think there's a difference between default and adaptive.

Comment: I've found this documentation: https://xorg.freedesktop.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration