# Adaptive acceleration for touchpad on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, touchpad, synaptics, 17.10, libinput

I recently updated from Ubuntu 16.04 running Unity to 17.10 running GNOME. Since the upgrade, I'm missing the adaptive acceleration feature on my touchpad. I absolutely loved it because it was more accurate for shorter distances.

On digging a bit, I found out that 17.10 uses GNOME with `libinput` instead of `synaptics`, but `libinput` uses a `flat` acceleration profile for touchpads by default (https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.4.3/pointer-acceleration.html#ptraccel-touchpad).

I also tried installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` on 17.10. This works fine, except for the fact that it is too cumbersome to enable 'Natural Scrolling' from the command line (https://askubuntu.com/a/206006). Another problem is that GNOME doesn't show touchpad settings with `synaptics` installed (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/292920).

I also tried fidgeting with `gnome-tweak-tool` under the 'Keyboard and Mouse' submenu on the sidebar but it has an option to select 'Acceleration Profile' only for a mouse, not for touchpads (see screenshot in [What are Mouse Acceleration profiles in the gnome-tweak-tool?](https://askubuntu.com/q/863671)).

Is there a way to enable adaptive acceleration for touchpads with `libinput` which has none of the above side effects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, try editing the key `speed` from the schema `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad`. The description for the key is as follows:

`Pointer speed for the touchpad. Accepted values are in the [-1..1] range (from "unaccelerated" to "fast"). A value of 0 is the system default.`

which strongly indicates the gnome key has something to do with touchpad acceleration. Use the dconf editor or gsettings through the command line and see if modifying this key has any effect.

Comment: Where did you get the definition for that key? Just curious so I could find the others.

Comment: You can see all keys with `gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad` and get the definition of a single key with `gsettings describe  org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad speed`.

Comment: Setting `speed` is not really adaptive acceleration. Judging by the keys `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse` has adaptive acceleration and `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad` simply hasn't :-(

Comment: Trying in Ubuntu 20.04. This only changes the mouse speed and not the acceleration. After the change in dconf editor, the same change is visible as mouse speed in the GUI

Answer (score 7):

In 17.10, you can also set the acceleration profile directly and disable mouse acceleration by setting `accel-profile` to `'flat'`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse accel-profile 'flat'
```

Alternatively, use `dconf-editor`:

[image: Disable mouse acceleration in Ubuntu 17.10]

Comment: I'm pretty sure, the mouse section applies to actual mouse devices that you hookup to the usb and not the touchpad.

Comment: I stand corrected....

Comment: @thebunnyrules Yes, sorry, you are right – I did not see the “for touchpad” part :)

Comment: Simon, I tried it out anyway and it did actually impact the performance of my touchpad. So no, I think you were right to recommend it.

Comment: just upgraded to 17.10, and found the decreased touchpad performance very disappointing as well. setting it to `'adaptive'` with the command you suggested fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Sorry this only helps if you're using Xorg, not Wayland according to [Arch Linux' Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput):

> For Wayland, there is no libinput configuration file. The configurable options depend on the progress of your desktop environment's support for them; see #Graphical tools.
>
> For Xorg, a default configuration file for the wrapper is installed to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf. No extra configuration is necessary for it to autodetect keyboards, touchpads, trackpointers and supported touchscreens.

For Xorg:

According to its [man page](http://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/libinput.4#CONFIGURATION_DETAILS) `libinput` also supports adaptive acceleration:

You should be able to add it as an option in xorg.conf, e.g. `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`:

```
Option "AccelProfile" "adaptive"
```

Answer (score 0):

[ubuntu 18.04 touchpad config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHFUb.png)

On ubuntu 18.04, the setting is slightly different, ranging as a double from -1 to 1.  Setting the touchpad setting to 1 accelerates the touchpad nicely.  I used dconf to edit the setting - worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a small script in .xinputrc in the home folder of the user

```
DEVICE=$(xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"|awk '/libinput\ Accel\ Speed\ \(/ {print $4}'|tr -d [:punct:])
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" $DEVICE 1.0
```

where the last argument (1.0) is a decimal value from 0.0 to 1.0.

```
0.0 -> no accel

1.0 -> max available accel
```

By the way, this also works on 20.04

Answer (score 0):

`dconf-editor` did what I wanted. With it, I disabled the acceleration for the magic trackpad.